# Can't click button in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I create a menuView in `self.view`,menuView has two subViews which are UIView.
this UIView contains 4 UIButton ,but i can't click any one of it. `userInteractionEnabled` set YES, button's frame set correct in View Debugging.
code:

**UPDATE:**[Project In Github](https://github.com/gshushu/tryView)

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    LeftMenuView *leftView=[LeftMenuView createLeftMenuView];
    leftView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.leftView=leftView;
    [self.view addSubview:leftView];
    //nightButton
    UIButton *nightButton=[self.leftView viewWithTag:6];
    [nightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    leftView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    //set
    UIButton *settingButton=[self.leftView viewWithTag:4];
    [settingButton addTarget:self.leftView action:@selector(push) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
```

**LeftMenuView.m:**this is a UIView class. It is the place i set button and menu.

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    [self addHeaderView];
    [self addButton];
    return self;
}
#pragma mark -add view to menu view
-(void)addHeaderView
{
    UIView *headViewUp=[[UIView alloc]init];
    headViewUp.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    headViewUp.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, yScreenWidth/2, 114);
    headViewUp.backgroundColor=ColorWithRGB(26, 31, 36);
    headViewUp.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    self.headViewUp=headViewUp;
    [self addSubview:headViewUp];
    UIView *headViewDown=[[UIView alloc]init];
    headViewDown.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    headViewDown.frame=CGRectMake(0, yScreenHeight-50, yScreenWidth/2, 50);
    headViewDown.backgroundColor=ColorWithRGB(26, 31, 36);
    self.headViewDown=headViewDown;
    [self addSubview:headViewDown];
}
-(void)addButton
{
    UIButton *settingButton=[self setFrame:CGRectMake(yScreenWidth*2/6, 64, yScreenWidth/6, 50 ) title:@"设置" image:@"Menu_Icon_Setting"];
    settingButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    settingButton.tag=4;
    [self resizeTextAndImageInButton:settingButton];
    [self.headViewUp addSubview:settingButton];
    UIButton *nightButton=[self setFrame:CGRectMake(yScreenWidth/4, 0, yScreenWidth/4, 50 ) title:@"白天" image:@"Menu_Day"];
    nightButton.tag=6;
    [self.headViewDown addSubview:nightButton];
}
-(UIButton *)setFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title image:(NSString *)imageName
{
    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8];
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    return button;
}
-(void)resizeTextAndImageInButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(button.imageView.frame.size.height ,-button.imageView.frame.size.width, 0.0,0.0)];
    [button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, 0.0,0.0, -button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width)];
}
```

the method of clilk button doesn't work.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? In `viewDidLoad` you never add those buttons to the view and in `addButton` you don't add targets to those buttons.

Comment: debug properly.

Comment: @WMios I add this button in LeftMenuView, and add add targets in viewDidLoad. This button can show but doesn't click.

Comment: is your view in scrollview?

Comment: @SwiftyCruz,no, it just a UIView . LeftMenuView has two subviews, also is view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through your code. you are doing one mistake that you are not setting the frame for "LefMenuView".Even you did not do this, its subview are visible but not touchable or clickable.

So try this. i run by adding below code. Now i am able to see the click actions.

```
Rule of thumb : if super view frame is Zero then all subviews are visible but not touchable.(Because you are touching out side of bounds).
```

ViewController.m

---

```
LeftMenuView *leftView=[LeftMenuView createLeftMenuView];
leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
leftView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing mistake While setting the target in you code .
please  do like this

```
[settingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

set   `settingButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`

Now handle the click event as below

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id) sender
{

   UIButton *btn=(UIButton*) sender;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a target for your button with the corresponding method

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aButtonMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This code needs the following

```
-(void)addButton
{
    UIButton *settingButton=[self setFrame:CGRectMake(yScreenWidth*2/6, 64, yScreenWidth/6, 50 ) title:@"设置" image:@"Menu_Icon_Setting"];
    settingButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    settingButton.tag=4;
    [self resizeTextAndImageInButton:settingButton];
    [self.headViewUp addSubview:settingButton];
    UIButton *nightButton=[self setFrame:CGRectMake(yScreenWidth/4, 0, yScreenWidth/4, 50 ) title:@"白天" image:@"Menu_Day"];
    nightButton.tag=6;
    **[nightButton addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aButtonMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];**
    [self.headViewDown addSubview:nightButton];
}
```

or

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        LeftMenuView *leftView=[LeftMenuView createLeftMenuView];
        leftView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        self.leftView=leftView;
        [self.view addSubview:leftView];
        //nightButton
        UIButton *nightButton=[self.leftView viewWithTag:6];
        [nightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        leftView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[nightButton addtoSubView:self.view]
        //set
        UIButton *settingButton=[self.leftView viewWithTag:4];
        [settingButton addTarget:self.leftView action:@selector(push) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[settingButton addtoSubView:self.view]
        }
```

you essentially create the same button twice but only for one set add a target and for the other set you don't add them to the view

Comment: I add it in - (void)viewDidLoad. With the button tag

Comment: In your viewDidLoad you don't add the button to the view in your addbutton mehtod you don't add a target

Comment: `-(void)addButton` is in the class of UIView .Should i add click method in UIView class? and i add it in viewDidLoad just now, but it can't click too.I post the project in Github .

Comment: in your ViewController.m you create a button set a selector and then never show it in the view, you need to add it to the view or it will never be used

Comment: I add it in view ,but it doesn't work too. And  you means UIButton *nightButton=[self.leftView viewWithTag:6]; this is a new button instead of the button i set with tag?